# Nilpotent Mappings

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation, jordan-normal-form

Got completely confused with this nilpotent and JCF stuff, need some help.

> Matrix $A_{n\times n}$ is nilpotent of order K,  $1\le k\le 4$

Need to find:

> a list of all possible dimensions of null(A), $null(A^2)$, ... ,  $null(A^{k-1})$

How do I do that?

Thank you!

Note: I kinda figured out how to do this below, but I am still a bit shaky on that one, so please correct

Comment: Do you know about jordan normal form?

Comment: @GitGud I'm in process of learning it, and the question above is the first step before finding jcf

Comment: Do you know about Schur decomposition (any matrix can be triangularized)?

Comment: @GitGud Is it helpful here?

Comment: Yes, it helps.${{{{}}}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\alpha_i=dim(\ker(A^i))$. In particular $(*)$ $\alpha_0=0,\alpha_k=n$ and , for every $i$, $\alpha_{i+1}-\alpha_i\geq 0$.

tmac_balla gave the (correct) solutions when $n=4$. Unfortunately, he killed the most important conditions, that are,

$(**)$ for every $i$, $\alpha_{i+1}-\alpha_i\leq \alpha_{i}-\alpha_{i-1}$.

Let $C(A)$ be the commutant of $A$. The previous values are important, because $dim(C(A))=\sum_{i\geq 0} (\alpha_{i+1}-\alpha_i)^2$.

Finally, for every sequence $(\alpha_i)_i$ satisfying $(*)$ and $(**)$, there is instance of $A$ s.t. its associated sequence is $(\alpha_i)_i$.

Answer (score 0):

**A solution for n = 4:**

The dimensions of null(A), null(A2), ... , null(Ak−1) depend on the given k for a certain case.

Important points are:

> 1. dim null($A^{k-1}$) $\gt$ ... $\gt$  dim null($A^2$) $\gt$ dim null($A$)
> 2. dim null($A^{k}$) = n

So, there are 4 possible values for k:

if k = 1, the only possible case is

> dim null(A) = 4

if k = 2, two cases are possible

> 1. dim null ($A$) = 3
>      dim null ($A^2$) = 4
> 2. dim null ($A$) = 2
>      dim null ($A^2$) = 4

if k = 3:

> dim null($A$) = 2
>
> dim null($A^2$) = 3
>
> dim null($A^3$) = 4

and if k =4:

> dim null($A$) = 1
>
> dim null($A^2$) = 2
>
> dim null($A^3$) = 3
>
> dim null($A^4$) = 4

Comment: This is wrong for $k=2$ (I didn't check the other cases, but I'm guessing you made the same mistake). Consider  $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0  & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\  0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\  0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$. Then $A^2=0_{8\times 8}$ and $\dim \left(\text{null}(A)\right)=4$.

Comment: thanks, I specified the case, solution is good for